# DocuSign Connect webhook not including HMAC header

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I've referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673644/docusign-connect-webhook-call-did-not-include-hmac-header-x-docusign-signature) StackOverflow question, but the responses were not helpful in my case.

I've setup DocuSign Connect to use the SOAP interface and checked the "Include HMAC Signature" for the Connect configuration. I've built my endpoint and can properly receive the envelope payload, but the request does not include the *X-DocuSign-Signature*.

I'm observing the headers by looking at the HttpContext once the WebMethod is called:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers
```

9 headers are being sent: Connection, Via, Content-Length, Content-Type, Expect, Host, User-Agent, SOAPAction, X-ClientSide.

I used @CountZero's recommendation from the other thread and set the EventNotification *IncludeHMAC* property on the envelope request, but that didn't result in the header being populated either. Also, I'd prefer to continue using the SOAP interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time what you're trying to do is unsupported. HMAC signatures are not included if the Connect SOAP interface is enabled. We don't have an open enhancement request for use of SOAP with HMAC, so if that's important as well, please contact DocuSign Support include your use-case so we can include your justification and file an enhancement request.

Envelope-level EventNotifications can support HMAC if `includeHMAC` is set to `true` in the `EventNotification` parameter block.

Comment: What is DocuSign's recommendations to verify the Connect payload (in particular, that it originated from DocuSign) using the SOAP interface? I was going to use HMAC as a security measure.

Comment: When using the SOAP interface, there should be an x509 signature that verifies the message content. I don't have specifics on implementing that, so you may need to open a new question for assistance on how it's used.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I'd recommend documenting that the SOAP interface is not compatible with HMAC. Perhaps it would be most useful to have a note on the Connect Admin page or to disallow checking the "Use SOAP Interface (SOAP Method: DocuSignConnectUpdate)" and "Include HMAC Signature - Recommended..." at the same time.

Comment: I was mistaken in my answer - Envelope-level EventNotifications can support hmac if `includeHMAC` is set to `true`. I'll pass along feedback to the Documentation team that SOAP and HMAC are not compatible.